# How to differentiate between fields with the same name in a query involving join

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` query that looks like this

```
SELECT t.*, b.* FROM tbl_t AS t
JOIN tbl_b AS b ...
```

Now, `tbl_t` and `tbl_b` both contain a field named `id`. I know that I can list all the fields and use an alias like this:

```
SELECT t.id AS tbl_t_id, t.sth, b.id AS tbl_b_id...
```

but the fields are much, and I need all of them, so I do not want to list them that way.

Please, is there a better or shorter way to differentiate between the `ids` from the different tables or access them correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Probably just to design your database a lot better than `tbl_t`.

Comment: @ChrisCooney the name of the tables are not tbl_t etc, I'm just trying to make the question simple and not typical to my app.

Comment: @Chibuzo There is no quick and easy way to do this. You will have to type out the column names and provide aliases to any duplicated names.

Comment: i don't understand the problem. Is it only an esthetic problem or is there a php underlying issue?